# double integral - reversing order of integration

Tags: calculus

> To Find:

$\int_0^1\int_{\arcsin(y)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec ^2{(\cos x)} dxdy$

> where

$R={(x,y),(0\le y\le 1), (\arcsin y\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2})}$

> (a Type II region) which is the same as

$R={(x,y), o\le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}}, (0\le y\le \sin(x))$

> a Type I region

$x=\arcsin y, y=\sin x$

> which gives

$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\sin x} \sec ^2{(\cos x)} dydx$

> and this is as far as I got -

$\int_0^\frac{pi}{2}sec^2(cos x)y|_0^{sin x}dx$

$\int_0^\frac{pi}{2}sec^2(cos x)sin xdx$

> where to from here?

$\int_0^\frac{pi}{2}sec(x)sin(x)dx$

$\int_0^\frac{pi}{2}tan(x)dx$

> which doesn't look right i.e. doesn't converge on interval?

Comment: $\sec^2(\cos x)\neq \sec(x)$  Instead I suggest a change of variables: try $u=\cos(x), \mathrm du = -\sin (x)\mathrm d x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far so good until you tried to equate $~\sec^2(\cos(x))~$ with $~\sec(x)~$.

Instead I suggest trying a change of variables such as: $u=\cos(x)$ means $\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}=-\sin(x)$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sec^2(\cos(x))\sin(x)\operatorname d x = -\int_0^1 \sec^2(u)\operatorname d u$$

Can you continue from there?